# Add header to Http Header

Tags: android, http-headers, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 for android project. But server code (which cannot be changed) is old and needs send some properties inside a header on HTTP header.

Server use soap so I decided to use ksoap2 for android but I couldn't find any example how to set http header of ksoap2 request(not inside soap envelope but inside of httpheader).

Is it possible?

If possible can anyone show me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the connection object and add the headers there.

```
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeout);
ServiceConnection conn = transport.getConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
//and others...
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers could be modified inside org.ksoap2.transport.call(String, SoapEnvelope, List, File) method.

**EDIT**

You can pass extra headers directly when calling `HttpTransportSE.call()`

example:

```
.
.
.
List<HeaderProperty> headers;
headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "utf8"));
headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Accept", "text/html"));

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(_soapAddress);

httpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope, headers);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please provide more information, possibly a source for your answer, as it stands this is a very poor answer.

Comment: The source is of answer ksoap2 sources codes - https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android